# INSERT statement does not insert data

Tags: sql, sql-insert, pgadmin

I have a database with the table superhero that is created like this:

```
CREATE TABLE Superhero 
(
    superhero_id serial PRIMARY KEY,
    superhero_name varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    superhero_alias varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    superhero_origin varchar(50) NOT NULL
);
```

If I try to insert data using a `INSERT INTO` statement, the environment says the data was successfully inserted, but the `SELECT` statement has an 'index out of range' error.

Here is the insert code:

```
INSERT INTO superhero (superhero_name, superhero_alias, superhero_origin)
VALUES ('Mage', 'dummyMage', 'test1'),
       ('Rogue', 'dummyRogue', 'test2'),
       ('Ranger', 'dummyRanger', 'test2');
```

And here is the select code:

```
SELECT * 
FROM public.superhero
ORDER BY superhero_id ASC
```

I also tried just inserting one item instead of three, and it didn't work.

And I tried to insert with a defined id, but it didn't work either:

```
INSERT INTO superhero
VALUES (0, 'Mage', 'dummyMage', 'test1' );
```

Comment: did you commit the insert transaction?

Comment: it may be because of "public." not in create and insert statement but you are using in select.

Comment: It could be that you are inserting and reading data from two differents Databases

Comment: @Somendra Kanaujia yeah, that was the problem. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Somendra Kanaujia suggested, the error was that I used the `public.superhero` in the `SELECT` statement, but nowhere else.